# Java Vector & ArrayindexoutofBoundsException

Tags: java, arrays, vector

Hello fellow developers!
I have this method for my java program below. It has 52 cards(vector v) that get shuffled and it should only print the ones that do not have a card with the same symbol following them( so if its Q of hearts then King of hearts it should skip King of hearts)
its working as it should be but i get:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:
>   Array index out of range: 52 at java.util.Vector.get(Vector.java:748)
>   at cardgame.Cardgame.shufflenosamebefore(Cardgame.java:507)

(507 is this line  `if (v.get(i).getsymbol() != v.get(i + 1).getsymbol()) {`)

```
 public void shufflenosamebefore() {
    Collections.shuffle(v);
    for (i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
        if (v.get(i).getsymbol() != v.get(i + 1).getsymbol()) {

            if (v.get(i).getsymbol() == 'T') {
                v.get(i).setsymbol('♣');
            }

            if (v.get(i).getsymbol() == 'P') {
                v.get(i).setsymbol('♠');
            }

            if (v.get(i).getsymbol() == 'C') {
                v.get(i).setsymbol('♦');
            }

            if (v.get(i).getsymbol() == 'H') {
                v.get(i).setsymbol('♥');
            }

            if (v.get(i).getnumber() == 11) {
                System.out.println("Card n." + (i + 1) + " is J " + v.get(i).getsymbol());
            } else if (v.get(i).getnumber() == 12) {
                System.out.println("Card n." + (i + 1) + " is Q " + v.get(i).getsymbol());
            } else if (v.get(i).getnumber() == 13) {
                System.out.println("Card n." + (i + 1) + " is K " + v.get(i).getsymbol());
            } else if (v.get(i).getnumber() == 0 || v.get(i).getnumber() == 1) {
                System.out.println("Card n." + (i + 1) + " is A " + v.get(i).getsymbol());
            } else {
                System.out.println("Card n." + (i + 1) + " is " + v.get(i).getnumber() + " " + v.get(i).getsymbol());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any input of why its giving me this error and the build fails? Thanks a lot!

Comment: This might help `for (i = 0; i < v.size() - 1; i++)`

Comment: Why use `Vector`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
v.get(i).getsymbol() != v.get(i + 1)
```

here the last element will fail as you are testing this element with the next element which does not exist.

Comment: Thanks but now a new problem arrived. its not checking the last card of the deck so it never prints it no matter what

Comment: for the last card just print whatever you need to print without this check. It is your code, you are free to change it your way.

Comment: I would recommend not doing these things in the same method. Have one method to create a new list with the satisfied cards, and another function to take a list and print it out in the way you like.

Answer (score 1):

When you get to the last card in the List your first if statement `if (v.get(i).getsymbol() != v.get(i + 1).getsymbol())` trows an IndexOutOfBounds Exception because  i+1=List.size() and that is out of bounds. you can fix it by using in your for loop `for (i = 0; i < v.size()-1; i++)`

Answer (score 1):

You are traversing to the last element in the list, then you are comparing with the next element.

By intuition, comparing the last element with the next element does not tend to be great. Solve it by traversing to the second last element in the list `i<size()-1`